# GWT plugin for eclipse failing on startup

Tags: google-eclipse-plugin

When I startup eclipse luna (4.4), after installing GWT plugin from this update site: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4
I'm getting a bunch of errors on my Error Log, all of them complaining about "Could not resolve module XXX", where XXX is: 
- com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android
- com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm [869]
- com.google.gwt.eclipse.core [867]
- com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext.e38

This is a detailed stack trace:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
>   com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm [869]   Unresolved requirement:
>   Require-Bundle: com.google.gdt.eclipse.core; visibility:="reexport"
>       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.google.gdt.eclipse.core; bundle-version="3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r44"; singleton:="true"
>          com.google.gdt.eclipse.core [854]
>            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform; visibility:="reexport"
>              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform; bundle-version="3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r44"; singleton:="true"
>                 com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform [863]
>                   Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
>
> at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

My environment is
OSX, Mountain Lion, running with Java 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem was the extremely old version of JDK being used. I downloaded jdk 1.7.x and it works now. Hope this helps